# 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

On Samsung T230 *(Android 4.4.2)* It works in both of the following

```
File firstFile = new File("mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.storagetest", "test.txt");
RandomAccessFile fileLittle = new RandomAccessFile(firstFile, "rw");

File scndFile = new File("mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.storagetest", "test2.txt");
scndFile.createNewFile();
```

*I've tried a lot of these devices are working in this way. T230 is an example*

On Hometech Tablet (*Android 5.1.1*) does not work.

```
File firstFile = new File("mnt/external_sd/Android/data/com.example.storagetest", "test.txt");
RandomAccessFile fileLittle = new RandomAccessFile(firstFile, "rw");

File scndFile = new File("mnt/external_sd/Android/data/com.example.storagetest", "test2.txt");
scndFile.createNewFile();
```

**I get an error as follows:**

> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Current AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
...
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried many different ways... **[requestPermissions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))** and **[android:maxSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)** does not change anything
Too much search but I could not reach a conclusion.

How can i create a file on SD Card.

*Important: I can read files directly, but cant change or create new file.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i create a file on SD Card.

You don't. Devices that ship with Android 4.4+ do not allow arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

You can indirectly work with removable storage via [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). There, you do not worry about exactly where the user is putting the data (external storage, removable storage, Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.).

Comment: Does it change anything root access? I am reading blog, I'll confirm soon,

Comment: @Abdullah: Root access should allow you to work with removable media. Also, system apps, at least pre-installed ones, can be granted rights to removable media by the device manufacturer (or, presumably, a custom ROM developer). Ordinary SDK apps, however, cannot. If you are interested in those sorts of issues, you might consider reading [Dave Smith's blog post](https://possiblemobile.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/) on the details of how this is implemented.